# Bitwise alternative modulo gives different results

Tags: java

I'm looking for an alternative for modulo, for Java. The reason is performance.

I have to run a script which loops some time and performs a modulo calculation each loop. Now I read on quite some websites there is a bitwise solution for this, but it gives different results in case of `1 % 3`.

```
 1 % 3; // results in 1
 1 & (3-1); // results in 0
```

Can somebody explain this? Most calculations went fine, but this is one combination I found which does not give equal results.

Comment: `1 & (n-1)` is equivalent to `1 % n` if `n` is a power of 2. It doesn't work for all numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For positive integers, `i & (n-1)` is equivalent to `i % n` if `n` is a power of 2. It doesn't work for all numbers. Otherwise we'd all be doing it the fast way all of the time.

Comment: So actually you are saying that in case if even numbers it should work, but in case of odd numbers it doesn't

Comment: No, **powers of two**. It works for 2,4 and 8. It doesn't work for 6 or 10.

Comment: alright! Thanks for your answer! That makes sense :) Guess I would stick with modulo then... Guess it will not be better performance wise if I first have to calculate the number is a power of two, before deciding to handle it bitwise or with modulo.

Comment: @ErikvandeVen It would not be better for performance. If it was, then modulo would already work that way =)

Comment: Makes much sense indeed ;)